# Stop user from changing focus(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I build a dialog box that take away focus from the parent window and force user for an input? Unless a user provide an input or press a cancel button, the parent window won't be accessible. So it's kind of a message box but with an input field. I found top-level method to create a top-level window but I couldn't find a method to stop user from accessing parent window. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive, but it looks like if you make a new class inherited from `TopLevel` but attach it to a parent, then call `self.transient(parent)` you should have something close to what you'd like. I am assuming that it'll block input to the parent window as well.

> The main trickery is done in the constructor; first, transient is used
>   to associate this window with a parent window (usually the application
>   window from which the dialog was launched). The dialog won't show up
>   as an icon in the window manager (it won't appear in the task bar
>   under Windows, for example), and if you iconify the parent window, the
>   dialog will be hidden as well

Check out [this page for more details](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: That seems to be a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew: It's customary to also up-vote the answer you accept if you think it's worthy.

Comment: @martineau He did right away, someone else downvoted. Or he took back his upvote I guess. Lost 2 rep, if that's any indication. Either way, the other answer is better. Wonder if I should consolidate the two since mines accepted already.

Comment: The link is dead by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Making the window transient is not the whole solution. A window that forces the focus to itself is called a "modal" window. The key is the "grab_set()" method. You can have modal windows that force the focus of the application, or that force the focus of the whole windowing system.

You can find more when you google for "Tkinter" in combination with "modal". One hit: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ModalWindow

Comment: Seems like a more complete solution. +1

Comment: Near the beginning of [Chapter 10. Dialog Windows](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/dialog-windows.htm) in the pythonware documentation there's a description of what the `grab_set()`method does. There even more useful information further down, including a dialog support class `Dialog` you can inherit from when creating your own dialogs.